# Why are conditional and marginal pseudo R^2 the same in this example?

Tags: lme4-nlme, r-squared, glmm

Here is a reproducible example:
The problem is that when I calculate Pseudo R^squared for the null model it gives 0.18 to conditional R^2, the variance explained by the random factor is not 0. However in the second model, the random factor explains 0. Can anyone understand what is happening here?

```
y <- c(0.7856780, 0.7180579, 0.7507567, 0.7133756, 0.7400243, 0.5755849, 0.8940106, 0.7641721, 0.6352975, 0.5873056, 0.6031032, 0.8178788, 0.9371824, 0.7217356, 0.8189858, 0.8341923, 0.4978015, 0.6959834) #Dependent variable
```

`fixedfactor <- c ("a","a","b","b","a","a","c","c","a","a","b","b","c","c","c","c","b","b") #fixed factor with three levels (a,b and c).`

```
randomfactor <- c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D","E","E","F","F","G","G","H","H","I","I")# Random factor. 18 sites, paired plots (9 levels).
df <- data.frame(y=y,fixedfactor=fixedfactor,randomfactor=randomfactor)#Create dataframe
```

I run a GLMM,

```
null_model <- lmer(data=df,y~(1|randomfactor),REML=F)
model1 <- lmer(data=df,y~ fixedfactor + (1|randomfactor),REML=F)

r.squaredGLMM(null_model)
 R2m       R2c
0     0.1842162

r.squaredGLMM(model1)
 R2m         R2c
0.377974    0.377974
```

Comment: @a_statistician thank you for the editing. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Sorry. I am not familiar with R. In fact I do not know what R2m and R2c mean.

Comment: Ok, thank you. It stands for Conditional R squared and Marginal R squared.

Comment: goto https://ecologyforacrowdedplanet.wordpress.com/2013/08/27/r-squared-in-mixed-models-the-easy-way/   Search 0.009962046   Maybe helpful.

Comment: From the link that @a_statistician shared. Is not a complete answere but maybe can help someone:
Paul Johnson says: "The only difference between R2m and R2c is in the numerator, which is Vfixed for R2m and Vfixed + Vrandom for R2c. If they are equal, Vrandom, which is the intersubject variance in your case, must have been estimated at zero. This suggests that the clustering of observations within subjects is either non-existent or too weak to detect."
Thank you!